# How to start project node.js error with name

Tags: node.js, npm

I need start the project https://github.com/oracle/bots-node-sdk and I don`t know a lot of node.js. I try follow the instructions, but I receive the errors.

```
npm install @oracle/bots-node-sdk
npm ERR! code ENOSELF
npm ERR! Refusing to install package with name "@oracle/bots-node-sdk" under a package
npm ERR! also called "@oracle/bots-node-sdk". Did you name your project the same
npm ERR! as the dependency you're installing?
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For more information, see:
npm ERR!     <https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#limitations-of-npms-install-algorithm>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\josiv\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-05T16_16_57_042Z-debug.log
```

I already try change name in file package.json and also I try command: **npm init "other_name"** and always the same error.

Edit:

I change name in file `package.json` and run `npm install @oracle/bots-node-sdk`. After `run npx @oracle/bots-node-sdk init` with successful:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Custom Component package 'bots-node-sdk-master' created successfully!
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Usage:
  npm start    Start a dev server with the component package

PS D:\Fontes\OracleDigitalAssistant-Bot\bots-node-sdk-master> npm start

> bots@2.1.3 start D:\Fontes\OracleDigitalAssistant-Bot\bots-node-sdk-master
> npm run bots-node-sdk -- --service .
> bots@2.1.3 bots-node-sdk D:\Fontes\OracleDigitalAssistant-Bot\bots-node-sdk-master
> bots-node-sdk "--service" "."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is saying there's a conflict with your project name and the dependency you're trying to install.

In your `package.json`, if the `name` property is "@oracle/bots-node-sdk" then change it to someone else and then run `npm install @oracle/bots-node-sdk` again.

Alternatively you can just delete the `package.json` file and then run `npm init -y`.

Comment: I followed your suggestion, but receive new message. I edited my question with the result.